# Remover espaços de um array de String

Tags: java, array

Como fazer para remover os espaços (não todos espaços, apenas o do começo e fim) de todos os índices de um array String em Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilizando [`trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--):

```
String[]  strArray = {" teste ", " teste ", " teste "};

for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++){
  strArray[i]  = strArray[i].trim();
}
```

Comment: Não sei como não pensei nisso

Comment: @felipe.rce é simples de fazer :)

Answer (score 3):

no **java-8** podes simplesmente fazer deste jeito:

```
String[] resultado = Arrays.stream(meuArray).map(String::trim).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Ou podes fazer desta versão mais "suja" sem criar um array final, o array passado será modificado automaticamente

```
Arrays.stream(meuArray).map(String::trim).toArray(unused -> meuArray);
```

Comment: E de um array? Isso ai não é bem um array, e sim uma lista.

Comment: @Articuno erro meu, tava habituado a fazer com listas, mas ja editei!

Comment: Eu não sei nada de Java 8, então não entendi muito bem, mas vou testar aqui para ver